# My JS RTE is sending a HTTP post request that my ASP.NET Core handler doesn't capture

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, tinymce

I'm trying to add a WYSIWYG rich text editor for my ASP.NET Core app with RazorPages. I'm using the TinyMCE editor. The editor works fine but I ran into a problem while implementing the insert img feature. I want it to allow users to import imgs and insert them into documents. I need to save the uploaded imgs (for now in my local storage).

The problem that I'm facing is that I cannot figure out how to communicate the javascript upload handler with the ASP http post request handler. Whenever I try to upload an image I get a HTTP error: 400

I created a Upload.cshtml.cs file with a OnPost method for handling the upload request. But it doesn't respond to the js upload handler sending the request.

Here's the file with upload handler and the RTE config:

```
const img_upload_handler = (blobInfo, progress) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log("Start");
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.withCredentials = false;
    xhr.open('POST', '/Upload');
    xhr.upload.onprogress = (e) => {
        progress(e.loaded / e.total * 100);
    };
    xhr.onload = () => {

        if (xhr.status < 200 || xhr.status >= 300) {
            reject('HTTP Error: ' + xhr.status);
            return;
        }

        const json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

        if (!json || typeof json.location != 'string') {
            reject('Invalid JSON: ' + xhr.responseText);
            return;
        }

        resolve(json.location);
    };

    xhr.onerror = () => {
        reject('Image upload failed due to a XHR Transport error. Code: ' + xhr.status);
    };

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', blobInfo.blob(), blobInfo.filename());

    xhr.send(formData);
});


tinymce.init({
    selector: '#MCEditor',
    language: 'pl',
    height: 400,
    plugins: [
        'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print anchor',
        'searchreplace code fullscreen',
        'insertdatetime media table paste code help'
    ],
    toolbar: 'save | undo redo | formatselect | ' +
        'bold italic backcolor | alignleft aligncenter ' +
        'alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | ',
    content_style: 'body { font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px }',
    file_picker_types: 'image',
    images_upload_handler: img_upload_handler

});
```

and here's the Upload.cshtml.cs OnPost method:

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost(IFormFile file)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(file);
            if (file == null || file.Length == 0)
            {
                return BadRequest("No file uploaded.");
            }
            var uploadsDirectory = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot", "images");
            var filePath = Path.Combine(uploadsDirectory, file.FileName);

            using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
            {
                await file.CopyToAsync(stream);
            }
            var response = new
            {
                location = "/images/" + file.FileName // Adjust this based on your path
            };

            return new JsonResult(response);
        }
```